# I need to show an PDF in which text of pdf will auto fit to the screen width and remaining text move to the next line

Tags: android, pdf

I am showing an PDF form URl via Google doc in my web view.

( webview.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+ UrlPdf))

It works but I want to use warp content functionality so that text of pdf should auto fit to the screen width and exceeded text move to the new line so I can scroll it.

I searched many SDKs to do this but didn't get success.

Below I attached an screen which shows my requirement.

[image]

Comment: PDF normally is not a format which can be Easily reflowed, it is explicitly made to display documents in the same way everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
** Try This**

WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); Use for Zooming Purpose
       settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);  Use for Zooming Purpose
       settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);      Use for Zooming Purpose
        mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
```